# How to multiply dataframe by 1 column of values within the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to multiply all values in my dataframe by a column of values creating a new DF in the process. Is this possible without seperating the values into two seperate DFs first?

[image: Screenshot of my data]

I want to multiply all the numbers to the right by the corresponding values found in the "Water Footprint" column.

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Multiplication in r is vectorised.  You may certainly do that.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged dplyr, so a potential solution is:

```
#Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

# Create the starting dataframe and add a column ("first_column")
# which contains random numbers with which to multiply the values of
# all the other columns
df1 <- penguins %>% 
  mutate(first_column = sample(1:100, nrow(penguins), replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(first_column, body_mass_g, flipper_length_mm, bill_length_mm)

# Perform the multiplication for every value
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = -c(first_column), .fns = ~ .x * first_column))

# Perform the multiplication for every value 
# and delete the first_column (if it's no longer needed)
df1 %>% 
  transmute(across(.cols = -c(first_column), .fns = ~ .x * first_column))
```